# How to display a data bound collection of int in a sorted manner

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have a very small collection of ints that I am displaying in a custom `ItemsControl`.  I'm not worried about performance since the collection is so small.  I would like the items to be displayed in ascending order and can't figure out the best way to do so.  I have successfully used a `CollectionViewSource` with a `SortDescription` to sort more complex objects, but it seems to require a property name to sort by.  I realize I could keep the underlying collection sorted or wrap my ints in a reference type to use the `SortDescription`, but both seem overkill.  Am I missing something?

I'd like to do something like this, where `MyCollection` is of type `ObservableCollection<int>`

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key={sortedView} Source={Binding MyCollection}>
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="???" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource>
<Grid.Resources>

...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource={StaticResource sortedView} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `.` as the property name:

```
<scm:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="." />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the source collection (`MyCollection`), rather than sort it in XAML.

Admittedly, there is no built-in way to sort an `ObservableCollection<T>`, but it's not very hard to implement. Here's a QuickSort implementation you can use as an extension method on any class that implement `IList<T>`:

```
static class QuickSortExtensions
{
    private static void CheckArgumentNull<T>(this T arg, string paramName) where T : class
    {
        if (arg == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
    }

    public static void CheckArgumentOutOfRange<T>(
        this T value,
        string paramName,
        T min,
        T max)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0 || value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName);
    }

    public static void QuickSort<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Comparison<T> comparison = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare;
        list.QuickSort(comparison);
    }

    public static void QuickSort<T>(
        this IList<T> list,
        IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        list.QuickSort(comparer.Compare);
    }

    public static void QuickSort<T>(
        this IList<T> list,
        Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        list.CheckArgumentNull("list");
        comparison.CheckArgumentNull("comparison");
        QuickSort(list, 0, list.Count - 1, comparison);
    }

    private static void QuickSort<T>(IList<T> list, int left, int right, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        if (right > left)
        {
            int pivot = left;
            QuickSortPartition(list, left, right, ref pivot, comparison);
            QuickSort(list, left, pivot - 1, comparison);
            QuickSort(list, pivot + 1, right, comparison);
        }
    }

    private static void QuickSortPartition<T>(IList<T> list, int left, int right, ref int pivot, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        T pivotValue = list[pivot];
        list.Swap(pivot, right);
        int tmpIndex = left;
        for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
        {
            if (comparison(list[i], pivotValue) <= 0)
            {
                list.Swap(i, tmpIndex);
                tmpIndex++;
            }
        }
        list.Swap(tmpIndex, right);
        pivot = tmpIndex;
    }

    private static void Swap<T>(
        this IList<T> list,
        int index1,
        int index2)
    {
        list.CheckArgumentNull("list");
        index1.CheckArgumentOutOfRange("index1", 0, list.Count - 1);
        index1.CheckArgumentOutOfRange("index2", 0, list.Count - 1);

        T tmp = list[index1];
        list[index1] = list[index2];
        list[index2] = tmp;
    }

}
```

To prevent the view from refreshing during the sort as the collection items are moved around, you can use `DeferRefresh`:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);
using (view.DeferRefresh())
{
    MyCollection.QuickSort();
}
```